# Unity3D, C# and uploading tracks to SoundCloud

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, upload, soundcloud

I am working on an app in Unity3D which can upload tracks to SoundCloud. I have been working on this for a while but i can't get it to work. I am using HttpWebRequest for the request to SoundCloud and this works fine on Unity for Windows. But when i try it on my Android device i get the following message: 'Request entity contains invalid byte sequence. Please transmit valid UTF-8.'.

Below is the part of code that i use (got it from somewhere on the internet).

I made sure i was uploading the same file on Windows as on Android and did the request to RequestBin. Now, when i compared the two, i noticed that the raw data is almost completely identical except for the end:

Ending Windows: ÿàþ³þDþÿýëýÅýÙý

Ending Android: ÿàþ³þDþÿýëýÅýÙý[FF]þÞýþûýCþxþZþ{þ

So as you can see, on Android there is more data. Can someone explain to me what is going on here?

I started with posts on the Unity community, now trying it here. [Here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/972511/encoding-on-android-not-correct.html) you can find my question on the unity website for more information.

```
public class SoundCloudScript {

//Enter app credentials from here http://soundcloud.com/you/apps
private const string _clientId = "xxx";
private const string _clientSecret = "xxx";
//enter username and password a soundcloud user, e.g. your own credentials
private const string _username = "xxx";
private const string _password = "xxx";

private string soundCloudToken;

//private WebClient _webclient = new WebClient();

public string Status { get; set; }

public IEnumerator GetTokenAndUploadFile(MonoBehaviour mono, FileInfo file)
{
    Debug.Log ( "GetTokenAndUploadFile() started");
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (p1, p2, p3, p4) => true;

    var form = new WWWForm ();
    form.AddField ("client_id", _clientId);
    form.AddField ("client_secret", _clientSecret);
    form.AddField ("grant_type", "password");
    form.AddField ("username", _username);
    form.AddField ("password", _password);

    //Authentication
    string soundCloudTokenRes = "https://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token";

    Debug.Log ( "Try to get token");
    WWW download = new WWW(soundCloudTokenRes, form);

    yield return download;

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(download.error)) 
    {
        Debug.Log ( "Error downloading: " + download.error );
    } 
    else 
    {
        var tokenInfo = download.text;
        tokenInfo = tokenInfo.Remove(0, tokenInfo.IndexOf("token\":\"") + 8);
        soundCloudToken = tokenInfo.Remove(tokenInfo.IndexOf("\""));
        Debug.Log(string.Format("Token set: {0}", soundCloudToken));

        UploadFile(file);
    }
}

public void UploadFile(FileInfo file)
{
    Debug.Log ("Start uploading!");

    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    var request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/") as HttpWebRequest;
    //some default headers
    request.Accept = "*/*";
    request.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
    request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
    request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6");

    //file array
    var files = new UploadFile[] 
    { 
        new UploadFile(file.FullName, "track[asset_data]", "application/octet-stream") 
    };

    //other form data
    var form = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
    form.Add("track[title]", "Some title");
    form.Add("track[sharing]", "private");
    form.Add("oauth_token", soundCloudToken);
    form.Add("format", "json");

    try
    {
        using (var response = HttpUploadHelper.Upload(request, files, form))
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        Debug.Log ("Upload success!");
    }
    catch (WebException wex) {
        if (wex.Response != null) {
            using (var errorResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wex.Response) {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(errorResponse.GetResponseStream())) {
                    string error = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    Debug.Log ("Error(1/2): Message: " + wex.Message);
                    Debug.Log ("Error(2/2): " + error);
                    //TODO: use JSON.net to parse this string and look at the error message
                }
            }
        }

    }

    //return "Nothing...";
    }
}

public class StreamMimePart : MimePart
{
    Stream _data;

    public void SetStream(Stream stream)
    {
        _data = stream;
    }

    public override Stream Data
    {
        get
        {
            return _data;
        }
    }
}

public abstract class MimePart
{
NameValueCollection _headers = new NameValueCollection();
byte[] _header;

public NameValueCollection Headers
{
    get { return _headers; }
}

public byte[] Header
{
    get { return _header; }
}

public long GenerateHeaderFooterData(string boundary)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append("--");
    sb.Append(boundary);
    sb.AppendLine();
    foreach (string key in _headers.AllKeys)
    {
        sb.Append(key);
        sb.Append(": ");
        sb.AppendLine(_headers[key]);
    }
    sb.AppendLine();

    _header = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());

    return _header.Length + Data.Length + 2;
}

public abstract Stream Data { get; }
}

public class StringMimePart : MimePart
{
Stream _data;

public string StringData
{
    set
    {
        _data = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value));
    }
}

public override Stream Data
{
    get
    {
        return _data;
    }
}
}

public class HttpUploadHelper
{
private HttpUploadHelper()
{ }

public static string Upload(string url, UploadFile[] files, NameValueCollection form)
{
    HttpWebResponse resp = Upload((HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url), files, form);

    using (Stream s = resp.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
    {
        return sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

public static HttpWebResponse Upload(HttpWebRequest req, UploadFile[] files, NameValueCollection form)
{
    List<MimePart> mimeParts = new List<MimePart>();

    try
    {
        foreach (string key in form.AllKeys)
        {
            StringMimePart part = new StringMimePart();

            part.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = "form-data; name=\"" + key + "\"";
            part.StringData = form[key];

            mimeParts.Add(part);
        }

        int nameIndex = 0;

        foreach (UploadFile file in files)
        {
            StreamMimePart part = new StreamMimePart();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FieldName))
                file.FieldName = "file" + nameIndex++;

            part.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = "form-data; name=\"" + file.FieldName + "\"; filename=\"" + file.FileName + "\"";
            part.Headers["Content-Type"] = file.ContentType;

            part.SetStream(file.Data);

            mimeParts.Add(part);
        }

        string boundary = "----------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");

        req.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
        req.Method = "POST";

        long contentLength = 0;

        byte[] _footer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("--" + boundary + "--\r\n");

        foreach (MimePart part in mimeParts)
        {
            contentLength += part.GenerateHeaderFooterData(boundary);
        }

        req.ContentLength = contentLength + _footer.Length;

        Debug.Log ("ContentLength: " + req.ContentLength);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        byte[] afterFile = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n");
        int read;

        foreach(var header in req.Headers)
        {
            Debug.Log(header);
        }

        using (Stream s = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            foreach (MimePart part in mimeParts)
            {
                s.Write(part.Header, 0, part.Header.Length);

                while ((read = part.Data.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    s.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                    Debug.Log ("Buffer: >>" + System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer) + "<<");
                }

                //Debug.Log ("Buffer: " + System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer));

                part.Data.Dispose();

                s.Write(afterFile, 0, afterFile.Length);
                Debug.Log ("Buffer-End: >>" + System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(afterFile) + "<<");
            }

            s.Write(_footer, 0, _footer.Length);

            Debug.Log ("Footer: >>" + System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_footer) + "<<");
        }

        return (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Crash! Message: " + e.Message);
        foreach (MimePart part in mimeParts)
            if (part.Data != null)
                part.Data.Dispose();

        throw;
    }
}
}

public class UploadFile
{
Stream _data;
string _fieldName;
string _fileName;
string _contentType;

public UploadFile(Stream data, string fieldName, string fileName, string contentType)
{
    _data = data;
    _fieldName = fieldName;
    _fileName = fileName;
    _contentType = contentType;
}

public UploadFile(string fileName, string fieldName, string contentType)
    : this(File.OpenRead(fileName), fieldName, Path.GetFileName(fileName), contentType)
{ }

public UploadFile(string fileName)
    : this(fileName, null, "application/octet-stream")
{ }

public Stream Data
{
    get { return _data; }
    set { _data = value; }
}

public string FieldName
{
    get { return _fieldName; }
    set { _fieldName = value; }
}

public string FileName
{
    get { return _fileName; }
    set { _fileName = value; }
}

public string ContentType
{
    get { return _contentType; }
    set { _contentType = value; }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working!! The problem was that at some point i used StringBuilder.AppendLine() to add a new line. This works fine on Windows, but on Android it didn't work... (i figured it out because the Content-Length was not the same for Windows and Android.)

I fixed it by instead of using 'StringBuilding.AppendLine()', i use 'StringBuilder.Append("\r\n")'